# Changing the selected value of a drop down based on the selected value of another drop down in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a dropdown box which is used to select a user from a database. I am then populating a number of textboxes with the user information from the database. I want to populate a dropdown box, which holds the user's role, dependent on which user is selected from the first drop down box.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim currentUser As String = editUserDropDown.SelectedValue
    Dim getUserDetails = "Select aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Roles.RoleName, [User Details].EmployeeName, [User Details].EmployeeAddress, [User Details].PersonalEmailAddress FROM aspnet_Users INNER JOIN [User Details] ON aspnet_Users.UserId = [User Details].UserId CROSS JOIN aspnet_Roles WHERE (aspnet_Users.UserName = '" & currentUser & "')"
    Dim getUserDetailsCmd As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(getUserDetails, DBConn)
    Dim getUserDetailsDS As New DataSet
    getUserDetailsCmd.Fill(getUserDetailsDS)

    Dim username = getUserDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
    Dim roleName = getUserDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    Dim name = getUserDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)
    Dim address = getUserDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3)
    Dim email = getUserDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4)


    userNameTxt.Text = username

    roleSelect.SelectedValue = roleName

    nameTxt.Text = name
    addressTxt.Text = address.Trim()
    emailTxt.Text = email
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where are you running into issues?  if you have already remedied the issue yourself post how you did it and mark it as the answer, please.  these are the things that help Stack Sites Grow.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this by doing a Post-back on the fist select drop down and then getting the content for the second one depending of the selection made on the first...

Hoped that helped!